# Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

Tags: flutter

e: C:\src\flutter\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\jitsi_meet-4.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\gunschu\jitsi_meet\JitsiMeetPlugin.kt: (66, 42): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jitsi_meet:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m 40s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

how to solv this problem please help .. my project link -- https://github.com/kibriatuhin/conf_call

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Goto the JitsiMeetPlugin.kt file and replace

```
constructor(activity: Activity) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
}
```

using this

```
constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess, but I think you upgraded to Flutter 3, and the plugin you are using (jitsi_meet) did not. You either have to downgrade to flutter 2.x, or even better fix the plugin.

Comment: yes brother  i  have upgraded to flutter 3.. please check my project . https://github.com/kibriatuhin/conf_call ..

Answer (score 0):

in jitsiMeetplugin.kt which is in the flutter sdk in my case the directory is C:\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\jitsi_meet-4.0.0\android\src\main\kotlin\com\gunschu\jitsi_meet
replace this code

```
constructor(activity: Activity) : this() {
    this.activity = activity
```

}

with

```
constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
    this.activity = activity
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Go to this path: {YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY}/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/JitsiMeetPlugin.kt

or

Also change from Android studio: Project/External Libraries/Flutter Plugins/jitsi-meet/src/main/kotlin/JitsiMeetPlugin.kt

replace this code

```
constructor(activity: Activity) : this() {
    this.activity = activity
}
```

with this

```
constructor(activity: Activity?) : this() {
        this.activity = activity
}
```